# Looking for a simple editor that allows me to visually edit hex color values

Tags: html, css, color-picker

I'm editing a CSS style sheet in Eclipse and I constantly have to copy out e.g. #FF9C21 into an HTML page to see what color it is.

What is the best CSS editor (or Eclipse plug-in) that would allow me to:

- **hover** over #FF9C21 to see a little square of that color
- **right click** on #FF9C21 to pick a new color from a visual color selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if [colorpicker](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/) is the right one for you.

Comment: +1 for nice tool, better than pixie which I used to use

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Aptana?

http://www.aptana.com/

You can also install Aptana as Eclipse plugin:

http://www.aptana.com/studio/download

Answer (score 0):

I know that firebug lets you hover over CSS color definitions and see what they are. Perhaps there's a mozilla plugin somewhere out there. Alternatively, you can use paint and go for `rgb(red,green,blue)`.

Answer (score 0):

the color picker in the firefox plugin [colorzilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/271) works pretty well if u dont need to be super exact. as a bonus u can eyedrop colors from webpages